# Should I notify 'under construction' websites to crawlers? If yes how?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, construction

I am currently developing a website which is going to take some time to finish. I need to move some 'stuff' to production frequently, while maintaining a `under construction` status. My front page will clearly mention that my website is under construction.

I know crawlers will access my URL before I am ready to go live. Should I tell them my site is under construction (no need to index)? If yes how?

P.S.: Eventually, I am ok to let them see my under construction front page.

Comment: There is no need to do that, more info on this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24419/coming-soon-pages-seo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the search engines indexing your content before you're ready, block them with robots.txt and meta tag.

Comment: I guess I can discard pages with robot.txt, but what do you mean with meta tag? Can you give an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: It should look like this and go in the head area of each page you want hidden. <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> this keeps your URLs from being indexed if there are links pointing to them from elsewhere. Additionally you could leave off the robots.txt and use "noindex, follow" this allows Google to crawl the pages and get information about/from them without adding them to the index. It overlaps somewhat with the robots.txt but is treated a little different.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry!  Published and be damned!  Avoid any mention of 'under construction'.  Hey, every site is a work in progress.  Maybe you could give us a link so that we could see the problem (or lack of problem).

My guess is that search engines (and readers) will love your site if it keeps on publishing new pages.