# Should I noindex a coming soon page?

Tags: seo, noindex

I am working on a coming soon page that will list our logo, contact form and a newsletter subscription. It is rather short and simple. In regards to SEO, should I set it `noindex nofollow` perhaps then?

Comment: See also: ["Coming soon" pages & SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24419/coming-soon-pages-seo)

Answer (score 3):

The effect of this decision on the SEO of the rest of your site, current or future, will be negligible.

If you want users to be able to discover this "Coming Soon" page on Google (and other search engines), then do not mark it as `noindex`. If you would rather people not find this page in Google search results, then mark it `noindex`. However, since the page is so lean, and especially if we assume that it has no quality backlinks, Google might not index it anyways even if you allow it to.

The `nofollow` keyword is [not really relevant or useful in this situation](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-long-term-noindex-follow-24990.html).

Comment: @jowety then why do you want to have it?